# Issue with sorting a column passed from parent to child component in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to pass a column from a parent component to a child component in Angular, and I'm encountering an issue with sorting on the column. Here's my code:

**Parent component**

```
<table-sorting-example matSort>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="another">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Another</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.another}}</td>
  </ng-container>
</table-sorting-example>
```

**Child component**

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Position</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.position}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Name</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.name}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Weight</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.weight}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Symbol</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.symbol}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

Child Component TS file

```
import {
  AfterViewInit,
  Component,
  ContentChildren,
  QueryList,
  ViewChild,
} from '@angular/core';
import { MatSort, Sort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import {
  MatColumnDef,
  MatTable,
  MatTableDataSource,
} from '@angular/material/table';

export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
  another: string;
}
const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  { position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B', another: 'A' },
  { position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C', another: 'B' },
  { position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N', another: 'C' },
  { position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O', another: 'D' },
  { position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F', another: 'E' },
  { position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne', another: 'F' },
];
/**
 * @title Table with sorting
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'table-sorting-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-sorting-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-sorting-example.html',
})
export class TableSortingExample implements AfterViewInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);

  @ViewChild(MatTable) myTable: MatTable<PeriodicElement>;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  @ContentChildren(MatColumnDef) private customCols: QueryList<MatColumnDef>;

  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    for (let col of this.customCols) {
      this.myTable.addColumnDef(col);
      this.displayedColumns.push(col.name);
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, I have used matSort on both the parent and child components. However, sorting on the "another" column doesn't seem to work. The other columns sort as expected.

I have checked the Angular documentation and other online resources, but I couldn't find a solution to this issue. Can someone please help me understand why the sorting on the "another" column is not working and how I can fix it?

You can find full code here on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sku9pd-fhjr5h?file=src/app/table-sorting-example.ts)

Answer (score 0):

You add the `customCols`  with the `addColumnDef` to the material table. My guess is you have to do something similar with the custom columns for sorting. Did you try to use the `register` method on `MatSort`. Something like:

```
for (let col of this.customCols) {
  this.myTable.addColumnDef(col);
  this.matSort.register({id: col.name, start: 'desc', disableClear: false});
  this.displayedColumns.push(col.name);
}
```

Comment: I have tried but it's not working. 

https://stackblitz.com/edit/sku9pd-fhjr5h?file=src/app/table-sorting-example.ts